# Replace null value using the select statement for ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

```
SELECT A.CABLE_NO,A.LOC_A,A.LOC_B, iif(isnull(B.LENGTH,'SITE',B.LENGTH) AS CABLE_LENGTH
FROM TABLE_A AS A, TABLE_B AS B
WHERE A.id =B.id
```

I would like to modify the above code so as to use with MS Access/JET database engine,

Table A contain the cable no and location a and location `b` column whereas Table `B` contain the length, some of the length field is empty i.e. `null`, 
I would like to replace the `NULL` value to `SITE` in the query result.

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis. iif(isnull(B.LENGTH),'SITE',B.LENGTH) AS CABLE_LENGTH

Comment: That should work assuming you fix the Parens problem @Jenn pointed out. Or you just use [`NZ(B.LENGTH,'SITE')`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx?CTT=1)

Comment: Thanks for point out the silly mistake, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.CABLE_NO,A.LOC_A,A.LOC_B,
    ISNULL(B.LENGTH,'SITE') AS CABLE_LENGTH
FROM TABLE_A AS A, TABLE_B AS B
WHERE A.id =B.id
```